# How to make height of CSS grid rows not affected by each other

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to have the height of CSS grid rows not to be affected by other rows?
Currently how it looks:
[Screenshot (the red lines is how I want the rows to behave)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VEWr.png)

Here is my CSS grid code:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header header header"
  "leftCol midTop rightCol"
  "leftCol midTop tileone"
  "leftCol midBottom tiletwo"
  "footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 0px;
}
```

If this is unachievable how do achieve this same result with another CSS structure?

Comment: You can change the `align-self` property of those grid items to `start`. By default, they have `sretch` value, since stretching to the whole row height is usually the desired behavior, but it's not inherent to Grid layout.

Comment: You can also set `align-items: start` to the grid container in order to make _all_ grid items have the auto height instead of stretching to the row height.

Comment: This nearly works! only problem is that the rows beneath do not move up also.

Comment: Quite simply...no. If the rows aren't the same height... **it's not a grid**.

Comment: You will need a new HTML structure as well too...but you haven't provided that as yet.

Comment: I've come up with a solution of using align-self on the first row of each column and then creating child div's inside of them to emulate rows beneath them.